# Jackson, deserialize class with private fields and arg-constructor without annotations

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2, jackson-databind

It is possible to deserialize to a class with private fields and a custom argument constructor without using annotations and without modifying the class, using Jackson?

I know it's possible in Jackson when using this combination: 1) Java 8, 2) compile with "-parameters" option, and 3) the parameters names match JSON. But it's also possible in GSON by default without all these restrictions.

For example:

```
public class Person {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "{firstName: \"Foo\", lastName: \"Bar\", age: 30}";
        
        System.out.println("GSON: " + deserializeGson(json)); // works fine
        System.out.println("Jackson: " + deserializeJackson(json)); // error
    }

    public static Person deserializeJackson(String json) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES);
        mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
        return mapper.readValue(json, Person.class);
    }

    public static Person deserializeGson(String json) {
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        return gson.fromJson(json, Person.class);
    }
}
```

Which works fine for GSON, but Jackson throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `jacksonParametersTest.Person` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{firstName: "Foo", lastName: "Bar", age: 30}"; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
```

It's possible in GSON, so I would expect that there must be some way in Jackson without modifying the Person class, without Java 8, and without an explicit custom deserializer. Does anybody know a solution?

- Update, additional info

---

Gson seems to skip the argument constructor, so it must be creating a no-argument constructor behind the scenes using reflections.

Also, there exists a [Kotlin Jackson module](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin) which is able to do this for Kotlin data classes, even without the "-parameters" compiler flag.
So it is strange that such a solution doesn't seem to exist for Java Jackson.

This is the (nice and clean) solution available in Kotlin Jackson (which IMO should also become available in Java Jackson via a custom module):

```
val mapper = ObjectMapper()
    .enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES)
    .registerModule(KotlinModule())     
        
val person: Person = mapper.readValue(json, Person::class.java)
```

Comment: create a empty constructor for `person`

Comment: But that requires modifying the class. My question is whether this is possible without modifying it, like with Gson. (I'll make this more explicit in my question.)

Comment: So you don't want to annotate the class, you don't want to use the parameter names solution, and you don't want a custom deserializer. Anything else before I try to write an answer?

Comment: Not really, I also haven't added new requirements to the question. The situation basically is: you have a large amount of immutable classes outside your codebase, how to deserialize them efficiently without boilerplate code. The solution probably lies in a custom Jackson module that doesn't exist yet, or to use the "-parameter" flag. (This flag is cumbersome, because 1) it requires recompilation and 2) IntelliJ ignores Maven compiler flags. But I have accepted the Kotlin Jackson module as solution to my project.

Comment: @Kalaiselvan, I upvoted your comment as it worked for my colleague. But I didn't provide a default/empty constructor, and I was still able to work it out. The only difference was I was using windows 10 and he used a Mac.

Answer (score 13):

### Solution with mix-in annotations

You could use *mix-in annotations*. It's a great alternative when modifying the classes is not an option. You can think of it as kind of aspect-oriented way of adding more annotations during runtime, to augment the statically defined ones.

Assuming that your `Person` class is defined as follows:

```java
public class Person {

    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // Getters omitted
}
```

First define a mix-in annotation abstract class:

```java
public abstract class PersonMixIn {

    PersonMixIn(@JsonProperty("firstName") String firstName,
                @JsonProperty("lastName") String lastName,
                @JsonProperty("age") int age) {
    }
}
```

Then configure `ObjectMapper` to use the defined class as a mix-in for your POJO:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES);
mapper.addMixIn(Person.class, PersonMixIn.class);
```

And deserialize the JSON:

```java
String json = "{firstName: \"Foo\", lastName: \"Bar\", age: 30}";
Person person = mapper.readValue(json, Person.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

Jackson provides the module [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/parameter-names) for solve your problem.

You must built your `ObjectMapper` as following:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        .enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES)
        .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule(JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES));
```

You must add `-parameters` as compiler argument.

Example for maven:

```
 <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.5.1</version>
       <configuration>
           <!--somecode-->

           <compilerArgument>-parameters</compilerArgument>

       </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

For gradle:

```
compileJava {
  options.compilerArgs << "-parameters"
}
```

Comment: The OP already mentioned this options and don't want it, possibly they don't run Java 8.

Comment: @user1803551 He mentions this option for Kotlin classes.

Comment: @user1803551 He says "So it is strange that such a solution doesn't seem to exist for Java Jackson." In my opinion He searches this solution. Jackson doesn't supported another way to solve the problem if you don't want to create custom deserializer.

Comment: He says *"so I would expect that there must be some way in Jackson without modifying the Person class, without Java 8, and without an explicit custom deserializer. Does anybody know a solution?"* Your solution requires Java 8.

Comment: The problem with Java 8 is not really Java 8 by itself, but the need for the "-parameters" option. The solution requires 1) recompilation of the classes (which may be classes outside the codebase) and 2) IntelliJ ignores maven compiler flags. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/v2/issue/IDEA-143742

Comment: @Devabc I know, when you use the "-parameters" you must compile the classes by `mvn compile` and if your class in outside you must create your custom `deserializer` or `mixin`

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no default constructor, jackson or gson want create instance by there own. you should tell to the API how to create such instance by providing 
custom deserialize.

here an snippet code

```
public class PersonDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Person> { 
    public PersonDeserializer() {
        super(Person.class);
    } 

    @Override
    public Person deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        try {
            final JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            final Person person = (Person) mapper.readValue(node.toString(),
                    Person.class);
            return person;
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            throw new IOException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then register simple module as to handle your type

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = jacksonBuilder().build();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Person.class, new PersonDeserializer());
```

Comment: The code gives an error at ``Person person = (Person) mapper.readValue(node.toString(), Person.class);``: ``Cannot construct instance of `jacksonParametersTest.Person` `` Also this is a custom deserializer solution, whereas I'm looking for one without. Gson is able to do it by default. Also Kotlin module of Jackson is able to do it: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin . I also found out that Gson skips the argument constructor, so it's creating a default no-arg ctor behind the scenes.

Comment: The question specifically says "without modifying the Person class, without Java 8, and _without an explicit custom deserializer_"

Answer (score -2):

**Only if you can change your class implementation, below solution works**

A simple solution is just to create a default constructor

`Person()` in `Person` class

```
public class Person {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String lastName;
    private final int age;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well... That's an obvious solution. But the OP mentioned: _"without modifying the class"_