# Kotlin UnrecognizedPropertyException with Jackson's ObjectMapper.readValue()

Tags: kotlin, jackson

Hi I'm trying out Kotlin, and normally I would be able to use the ObjectMapper in Java. What I'm trying to do is store some KeyBind Array that contains data on a keybind and what it should to e.g. pressing the combination CTRL+SHIFT+X should "EXIT" but in Kotlin I seem to get:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "binds" (class Overlay.KeyBinds$Companion), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 11] (through reference chain: Overlay.KeyBinds$Companion["binds"])

at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:60)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:822)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:1152)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1589)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownVanilla(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1567)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:294)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:151)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2902)
at Overlay.KeyBinds$Companion.importer(KeyBinds.kt:51)
at Overlay.KeyBindIOTest.importer(KeyBindIOTest.java:45)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

The keybinds file that should be generated by the test seems to produce the output I want it to produce:

```
{"binds":[{"keyState":{"shiftHeld":true,"ctrlHeld":false,"altHeld":false,"key":30},"function":"EXIT"},{"keyState":{"shiftHeld":false,"ctrlHeld":false,"altHeld":false,"key":1},"function":"OPEN"}]}
```

**So, I'm not sure why it is failing on importing the Object from the file, anyone have any clues?**

My Kotlin code:

```
data class KeyBind(var keyState: KeyState, var function: String)

data class KeyBinds(var binds: Array<KeyBind>)
{
override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean
{
    if (this === other) return true
    if (javaClass != other?.javaClass) return false

    other as KeyBinds

    if (!Arrays.equals(binds, other.binds)) return false

    return true
}

override fun hashCode(): Int
{
    return Arrays.hashCode(binds)
}

fun exporter(location: String)
{
    var kb_file = File(location)

    if (kb_file.exists())
        kb_file.delete()

    var objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
    objectMapper.writeValue(kb_file, this)
}

companion object
{
    fun importer(location: String): Companion?
    {
        var kb_file = File(location)

        if (kb_file.exists())
        {
            var objectMapper = ObjectMapper()
            return objectMapper.readValue(kb_file, KeyBinds.javaClass)

        }
        return null
    }
}
}
```

My JUnit test:

```
public class KeyBindIOTest
{
private KeyBinds keyBinds = new KeyBinds(new KeyBind[]
{
        new KeyBind(new KeyState(true, false, false, 30), "EXIT"),
        new KeyBind(new KeyState(false, false, false, 1), "OPEN")
});
static final String TEST_LOCATION = System.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + File.separator + "TEST" + File.separator + "keybinds";

@Before
public void before()
{
    // Create Test Dir if it doesn't exist.
    File f = new File(System.getenv("LOCALAPPDATA") + File.separator + "TEST");
    if (!f.exists())
        f.mkdir();
}

@Test
public void exporter()
{
    keyBinds.exporter(TEST_LOCATION);

    // Verify file was created
    File f = new File(TEST_LOCATION);
    assertTrue(f.exists());
}

@Test
public void importer()
{
    assertEquals(keyBinds, KeyBinds.Companion.importer(TEST_LOCATION));
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I fixed this particular error by changing:

```
return objectMapper.readValue(kb_file, KeyBinds.javaClass)
```

to:

```
 return objectMapper.readValue(kb_file, KeyBinds::class.java)
```

It seems using .javaClass will tell the ObjectMapper the class is Companion instead of what you wanted it to be.

Unfortunatelly that's not the end of the errors now I end up with:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `Overlay.KeyBinds` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (File); line: 1, column: 2]

at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1451)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1027)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1297)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4013)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2902)
at Overlay.KeyBinds$Companion.importer(KeyBinds.kt:53)
at Overlay.KeyBindTest.importer(KeyBindTest.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this particular error by changing:

```
return objectMapper.readValue(kb_file, KeyBinds.javaClass)
```

to:

```
return objectMapper.readValue(kb_file, KeyBinds::class.java)
```

It seems using .javaClass will tell the ObjectMapper the class is Companion instead of what I wanted it to be.

**The second error I received is fixed by this:**

[Jackson, deserialize class with private fields and arg-constructor without annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570931/jackson-deserialize-class-with-private-fields-and-arg-constructor-without-annot)