# How to fix JSON decoding error in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-webflux

I'm sending a User object through REST which contains a Set of `SimpleGrantedAuthority` objects. On the receiver side, I'm getting an exception:

> org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException: JSON decoding error:
>   Cannot construct instance of
>   `org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority`
>   (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object
>   value (no delegate- or property-based Creator);

I'm using the default JSON mapper which Spring Boot 2.1.2 provides. On the receiving side, I'm using WebFlux's WebClient (WebTestClient in this case).

Can anyone explain to me why am I getting this error and how to solve it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47570931/jackson-deserialize-class-with-private-fields-and-arg-constructor-without-annot?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`SimpleGrantedAuthority`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/authority/SimpleGrantedAuthority.java) is not suitable for automatic mapping with Jackson; it has no no-arg constructor and no setter for the `authority` field.

So it needs a custom *deserializer*. Something like this:

```
class SimpleGrantedAuthorityDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<SimpleGrantedAuthority> {
    public SimpleGrantedAuthorityDeserializer() {
        super(SimpleGrantedAuthority.class);
    }
    @Override
    public SimpleGrantedAuthority deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode tree = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        return new SimpleGrantedAuthority(tree.get("authority").textValue());
    }
}
```

Register it with Jackson globally like this:

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule().addDeserializer(
                      SimpleGrantedAuthority.class, new SimpleGrantedAuthorityDeserializer()));
```

Or annotate the field(s) with:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = SimpleGrantedAuthorityDeserializer.class)
```

Note: you don't need a *serializer* because `SimpleGrantedAuthority` has the `getAuthority()` method, which is usable by Jackson.

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm.

Comment: If you're annotating the signature `public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities()` make sure to use `contentUsing`, so `@JsonDeserialize(contentUsing = SimpleGrantedAuthorityDeserializer.class)`, otherwise the deserializer gets the entire collection node to deserialize at once.